# Adding integer values inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a noob here so hope I have given enough info.
I have an assignment that asks me to make a javascript app that performs the following...

A book shop needs to keep a track of how many books are sold in a day and the price of each book. 
Create an application, using an array which asks the user to:

1. Enter each book name and price (Sample of 5 books is sufficient).
2. Displays each book and price on screen.
3. Calculates the total price of books sold and displays total on screen.
4. Prints the screen display.

I have 3 divs in my HTML with IDs -  `"nameOfBook"`, `"priceOfBook"` and `"displayTotal"`.

I have created two arrays with for Loops to display `"nameOfBook"` and `"priceOfBook"` on the page.

The problem I'm having is in getting it to add the prices of the books and display this total to my `"displayTotal"` div.

Here's the JS..

```
function addBooks()
{
  var nameBook = new Array();

  for(i=0; i<5; i++)
  { 
    nameBook = prompt("Enter name of Book","");
    document.getElementById("nameOfBookDiv").innerHTML += nameBook + "<br>";

    var priceBook = new Array();
    priceBook = prompt("Enter price of Book","");
    document.getElementById("priceOfBookDiv").innerHTML += priceBook + "<br>";
  }

  var total = 0;

  for(var i in priceBook)
  {
    total += priceBook[i];
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("displayTotal").innerHTML += total);
  }
}
```

Comment: check my answer, it works perfectly, then if you want change the way you want to display your data in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it like this:

```
function addBooks() {
    var nameBook = new Array();
    var priceBook = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        var bookName = prompt("Enter name of Book");
        nameBook.push(bookName);

        var bookPrice;
        while (isNaN(parseInt(bookPrice = prompt("Enter price of Book")))) {
            alert("Enter a valid number as a price!")
        }

        priceBook.push(parseInt(bookPrice));

    }
    document.getElementById("nameOfBookDiv").innerHTML += nameBook.join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("priceOfBookDiv").innerHTML += priceBook.join("<br>");


    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < priceBook.length; i++) {
        total += priceBook[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("displayTotal").innerHTML = parseFloat(total);
}
```

and it is your working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z4MY/)

Comment: -1 `nameBook.push(...)` and then `...innerHTML += nameBook`, `for (...) { total += ...; ...innerHTML += total; }` is also mistake

Comment: @Boris Šuška: I was changing my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few logical mistakes in your code:

1. You don't need define `nameBook` as an Array (you don't need to store all book names)
2. You should define total variable and initialize it to 0
3. You should use variable for getting value from the user, print the content of the variable into `priceOfBookDiv` and add this value to the total.
4. First count a total and then print it to the `displayTotal` div (in your example you print a partial results of the total value)

Here is a working [code](http://jsfiddle.net/suska/3KQHx/):

```
function addBooks()
{
    var total = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5 ; i++)
    { 
        var nameBook = prompt("Enter name of Book","");
        document.getElementById("nameOfBookDiv").innerHTML += nameBook + "<br>";

        var priceBook = parseInt(prompt("Enter price of Book",""));
        document.getElementById("priceOfBookDiv").innerHTML += priceBook + "<br>";
        total += priceBook;
    }

    parseFloat(document.getElementById("displayTotal").innerHTML += total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having some fundamental programming issues; what does it mean to 'assign' a variable? How do you store a collection of values for use later on in a program?

You are recording the price of the book inside of `prompt("Enter price of Book", "");`.
What you want to do is modify the priceOfBookDiv innerHTML to show the price entered in the prompt, which you have done, but you forgot to store the value of the prompt in a collection of values for use later on. The simplest way to do this is an Array.

```
var arrayOfPrices = [];

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  ...
  var priceOfSingleBook = prompt("Enter price of Book", "");
  document.getElementById("priceOfBookDiv").innerHTML += priceOfSingleBook;
  arrayOfPrices.push(priceOfSingleBook);
}

var total = 0;
for (var i in arrayOfPrices) {
  total += arrayOfPrices[i];
  ...
}
```